# How do I make an X potion?

Tags: the-gold-factory

> Effect: **They told me not to use this potion**
>   How to make: **They also don't tell me how to make it**

Can *you* tell me how to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the source code of the page

Btw that effect of the potion doesn't help you in battles

EDIT: It seems that i get down votes, I will explain this a little more further

> The real text:
>
> X Potion (not the Candy Box 2's)
> Effect: Unknown
> How to make: Mix all potions listed above (1 each potion) and add 100000 gold bars and 100000 iron bars

Comment: What exactly is the effect of this potion?

Comment: It just gives you the name Player